# NodeJS Async - Continue execution for multiple http requests even if some fail

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am trying to make multiple HTTP requests and cumulate, display the results in NodeJS using the following code:

```
const async = require('async');
const request = require('request');

function httpGet(url, callback) {
  const options = {
    url :  url,
    json : true
  };
  request(options,
    function(err, res, body) {
      console.log("invoked")
      callback(err, body);
    }
  ).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
}

const urls= [
  "http://1.2.3.4:30500/status/health/summary",
  "http://5.6.7.8:30505/status/health/summary"
];

async.map(urls, httpGet, function (err, res){
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    console.log(res);
});
```

The problem here is, if the first request(http://1.2.3.4:30500/status/health/summary) fails (like connection refused etc.), the second one does not go through. I know that I am making a silly mistake but cannot find it. Any help appreciated !

Comment: I think it happens because `request` is synchronous. Please take a look https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Comment: why dont u used `async.series`? on first success to for other. @hisener is right. request function is sync.

Comment: `request` _isn't_ synchronous! The semantics of `async.map()` are such that when an error happens, the final callback is called immediately.

Comment: @robertklep async.map is works in parallel. so no guaranty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In async.map if one of the calls passes an error to its callback, the main callback (for the map function) is immediately called with the error(this is the problem in your case). In order not to terminate on the first error, don't call the callback with err param in your httpGet.

Use async each, it receives a list of arguments and a function, and calls the function with each element, make sure in your httpGet inside on error you call the callback, without the err, this will make rest of the calls to continue even if there was an error in some of the calls. This can work for map too but, I think the more suitable function for your case is async.each, instead of map, also you can limit the number of concurrent calls with eachLimit method.

Check https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

```
const async = require('async');
const request = require('request');

function httpGet(url, callback) {
    const options = {
        url :  url,
        json : true
    };
    request(options,
        function(err, res, body) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                callback();
                return;
            }
            console.log("invoked")
            callback(null, body);
        }
    ).on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback();
    });
}

const urls= [
    "http://1.2.3.4:30500/status/health/summary",
    "http://5.6.7.8:30505/status/health/summary"
];

async.each(urls, httpGet, function (err, res) {
}, function (err, res) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `async.map` NOT to fail fast you could do it like this

```
const async = require('async');
const request = require('request');

function httpGet(url, callback) {
  const options = {
    url :  url,
    json : true
  };
  request(options,
    function alwaysReportSuccess(err, res, body) {
      callback(null, {
        success: !err,
        result: err ? err : body
      });
    }
  ).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
}

const urls= [
  "http://1.2.3.4:30500/status/health/summary",
  "http://5.6.7.8:30505/status/health/summary"
];

async.map(urls, httpGet, function alwaysOk(_, res){
    console.log(res); // will be an array with success flags and results
});
```